# please give regex for the below format

Tags: java, regex

I have given sample data below, please give me java regex to get Expected output.

```
String str="name=\"balaji\" address=\"bangalore madiwala\"";
```

I have tried something like below,

```
String[] str1=str.split("\\s");
```

Output:

```
str[0]-> name="balaji"
str[1]-> address="bangalore
str[2]-> madiwala"
```

Expected output:

```
str[0]-> name="balaji"
str[1]-> address="bangalore madiwala"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't exist to do your work for you. Show what you have tried (more than trivial non-attempt), and explain why it didn't work for you.

Comment: then what does stackoverflow do? whenever I post a question I used to get same response. This is not good.

Comment: You need to show you've made an effort to solve your problem rather than just post it here. "Please give me a solution as soon as possible" suggests you just expect people to hand you a solution without you having demonstrated any understanding, which wouldn't result in you *learning*, just continuing and then posting the next item in your to-do list when you can't complete that in two minutes of effort either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split using this regex:

```
String[] tok = str.split("(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) +");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cC3pF0/1)

This is matching 1 or more space only if it is outside quote by looking ahead even number of quotes after spaces.

**Code:**

```
String str="name=\"balaji\" address=\"bangalore madiwala\"";
String[] toks = str.split("(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) +");
for (String tok: toks)
   System.out.printf("%s%n", tok);
```

**Output:**

```
name="balaji"
address="bangalore madiwala"
```

#### [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/zCRlv7)

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply. but the code u provided its giving same output which I mentioned in my question.

Comment: That's not correct. See code in updated answer above and new demo link of working code.

Comment: could you please explain me?

Comment: Actually I had already written an explanation of this regex 3 hours back in my answer. Also check regex101 demo link for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Pattern` and matching group:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("name=(\".*\")\saddress=(\".*\")");
Matcher m = p.matcher("name=\"balaji\" address=\"bangalore madiwala\"");
String name = m.group(1);
String address = m.group(2);
```

Here is a visualisation:

[image: Visual regex]

You can change the key `name` and `address` by `\w+` for something more generic.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.I think you have hard coded. I am not sure the keys like name/address. so plz dont consider keys.

Comment: @thambisetty Answer edited, you can use `\w+` but in this case it will be hard to indentify the key without look ahead (maybe using multiple matching group, but it will quickly become unreadable). So please refer to anubhava's answer :)